# how to configure ldap group in drupal 7

Tags: 7, authentication-authorization

Drupal 6 and LDAP Integration the configuration was easy: Check "Groups exist as LDAP entries where a multivalued attribute contains the members' CNs" + set groups DN to "ou=Groups,dc=htrueta,dc=intranet" and "Attribute holding group members:" to "memberUid".

but in Drual 7, if I need do the similar configuration,  do not know what I need pick for each selections such as  name of group object class, attribute in user entry containing groups, ldap group entry attribute holding user's DN, CN, etc,  user attribute held in "LDAP Group entry attribute holding..." and so on

thanks,

Comment: Which LDAP module are you using? https://drupal.org/project/simple_ldap works really quickly out of the box, and often you can get away with using whatever the server returns.

Comment: I am using the LDAP module (Lightweight Directory Access Protocol (LDAP)) before, now I switched to Simple LDAP modlule.  but I got the following error:SimpleLdapException: Invalid DN syntax in SimpleLdap::ldap_read() (line 1116 of /var/www/drupal/sites/all/modules/simple_ldap/SimpleLdap.class.php).  any idea?